# How to import/use images in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to know how to use an image in Winform. I am successful in manual coding of controls such as (textbox, labels, buttons and etc) but when it comes to referencing like, adding BackgroundImage property, I have no idea how to do this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() 
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    private void InitializeComponents()
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = ??
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you :D

Comment: You want the code specific to Images?

Comment: Yup! I want to manipulate it like making that image as my form's background image, or let's say I want to put it in a picturebox and etc. I have made a bmp image file (For shaping windows forms to irregular shape) and wanting it as my form's background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make it as a bitmap first to be used as background image:

```
this.BackgroundImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap("your image path");
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks it works! But what if I changed terminals, Is there a way for my code to search for the image that I want instead of putting its direct path?

Comment: That isn't inside the debug or the executable file folder

Comment: you could specify your image path in absolute path, then the code can locate the file easily :) -if the answer helps, please kindly select it as answer :P